# How to align the content of two divs vertically?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align two `div`s horizontally inside my HTML: the first one contains an image and the second a text, and this is the used code:

```html
<div style="float: left; width: 55px;">
  <img src="../img/look.svg" alt="">
</div>

<div style="display: inline-block;">
  <span> Look for cases </span>
  <span> from people near you. </span>
</div>
```

I tried many methods, but I've been unable to get the text line in the same level as the image vertical axis, and the text inside the second `div` gets displayed very far from the image vertically.

So, is there any possibility to fix that?

Comment: Above you code you say you want to align them vertically, but after your code you say you're trying to align their vertical axis?  Assuming you do mean horizontal alignment, have you tried setting both divs to `float: left;` inside a container div wide enough to let them sit side-by-side?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is with the `float`. The `vertical-align: middle; line-height: 1;` will fix the issue:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 1;
}

div:first-child {
  width: 55px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="//placehold.it/50?text=DP" alt="">
</div>

<div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 1;">
  <span> Look for cases </span>
  <span> from people near you. </span>
</div>
```

**Preview**

**Top Alignment:**

[image]

**Middle Alignment:**

[image]

The `vertical-align` decides the vertical alignment. If you want the image and text to be on the same line, use `vertical-align: top`.

Comment: really?? this such a poor solution, rather a hack actually. Using inline-styles too?

Comment: @dippas Why do you think this is a poor solution or a hack? This is one of the best solution, which works for older browsers as well. Tell me what you think the better approach will be.

Comment: @dippas Agree with you on inline-styles buddy. Sorry about that.

Comment: I thought you were using `float` + `inline-block` , sorry. still OP says: *but I've been unable to get the text line in the same level as the image vertical axis* , so I'm guessing OP wants top aligned no middle aligned

Comment: @dippas No worries. I have been breathing and seeing CSS all my life buddy. :)

Comment: And I see you now change it ;)

Comment: @PraveenKumar That worked. But the problem now is that I'm getting the text in the top of the image.

Comment: @user6039980 I gave you two solutions... You want it in the middle?

Answer (score 4):

A few things first:

- don't use inline styles
- don't mix `float` with `inline-block`

---

### Option 1: using flebox

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <section>
  <div>
   <img src="//dummyimage.com/55x55" alt="">
  </div>
  <div>
   <span> Look for cases </span>
   <span> from people near you. </span>
  </div>
 </section>
```

### Option #2 using  inline-block

---

```css
div {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  margin-right:10px
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="//dummyimage.com/55x55" alt="">
</div>

<div>
  <span> Look for cases </span>
  <span> from people near you. </span>
</div>
```

### Option #3 using float

```css
div {
  float: left;
  margin-right:10px
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="//dummyimage.com/55x55" alt="">
</div>

<div>
  <span> Look for cases </span>
  <span> from people near you. </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`flexbox` to the rescue.

I added your `div`s inside another one, which will align its items. In my CSS my image has 100px so I changed the width to 100px. Change yours accordingly.

```css
.halign {
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="halign">
<div style="width: 100px;">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" alt="">
      </div>

      <div>
        <span> Look for cases </span>
        <span> from people near you. </span>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to seprate the CSS and HTML and do not mix  `display:inline-block` with `float:left`. Also use `clear:both` after both div

```
 <style>
        .fisrstDiv {
          float: left;
          display:block;
        }
         .secondDiv {
          float: left;
          display:block;
        }
      .clear {
          clear: both; 
        }
    </style>
```

HTML

```
<div class="fisrstDiv">
  <img src="//placehold.it/50?text=DP" alt="">
</div>

<div class="secondDiv">
  <span> Look for cases </span>
  <span> from people near you. </span>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```