# Vertical center div content / text

Tags: html, css, text, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

I have two `divs` next to each other. Each `div` contains some text (again in different `divs`). How can I vertically align the content (text) in the `divs`?

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/f5uxz4mx/12/)

EDIT: the duplicate-proposals do not solve my issue. I already tried the solutions presented there.

Comment: something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/f5uxz4mx/18/

Comment: just adding `padding-top:100px;` does not make it properly vertically aligned. thanks for your help, though.

Comment: Try these instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865455/center-text-inside-two-divs-horizontally and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37493976/how-to-align-the-content-of-two-divs-horizontally

Comment: do you mean you want them vertically centered? because they are already vertically aligned.

Comment: yes, sorry. i mean vertically centered.